# Which SDK is used for Android 3.3?

Tags: android

Which SDK do I use if I'm developing for a device running on Android 3.3? The closest, version number-wise, is 3.2.

Comment: See the **API** Levels table here to decide respective Platform Versions: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use 3.2. The Android SDK only has a new version if it includes "new" features from the last version. Therefore, you just round down to the nearest SDK. 4.0.4 uses 4.0.3, 2.3.7 uses 2.3.3, and 3.3 would use 3.2.

Note, however, there is no publication of Android 3.3. Take a look at the [API levels documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) for a list of the valid versions. (Thanks to **@uDaY** for the link + info.)

Comment: add this link to your answer to add more value: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html ;)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist... that is, there is no [Android 3.3](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html).